# Find which box was clicked (or enter keypress)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 containers and I need to know which one was clicked on, or when they press the "enter" key when focused on the input box.

How can I modify my code to be able to do that?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/qjs7c86v/)**

HTML (only showing 2 of the containers here):

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="container e_type1" data-custom-data="e_type1">
        <div class="header"><h2>E Type 1</h2></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <input type="text" name="item_level" value="1" class="item_level" min="1" step="1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container e_type2" data-custom-data="e_type2">
        <div class="header"><h2>E Type 2</h2></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <input type="text" name="item_level" value="1" class="item_level" min="1" step="1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Progress">
    <p>
        <div id="progressbar">
            <div class="progress-label"></div>
        </div>
    </p>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

JS Snippet (full code can be found in the JSFiddle)

```
// Image container was clicked.
//  Get data and send first Ajax request.
$(".image").click(function () {
    //console.log("Let's Start! Image container was clicked");
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    var e_type_var = $(".container").data("custom-data"),
        item_level_var = $(this).$("#item_level").val();
        alert(e_type_var + " was clicked");
    forgeAjax(e_type_var, item_level_var, 'first_req', function (error) {
        // By default, show Cancel button.
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            buttons: [{
                text: "Close",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }]
        });
        // Focus Cancel button
        $('.ui-dialog button:eq(1)').focus();
        // If there's no error returned, show Cancel and Button2 buttons.
        if (!error) {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                        'Button2': function () {
                        $("#message").html("");
                        startProgressBar(e_type_var, item_level_var);
                    }
                }
            });
            // Focus Button2.
            $('.ui-dialog button:eq(2)').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Thank you everyone for pointing out the `id="item_level"`. It was an oversight on my part, does not explain why the code does not work though. And it has been removed from the question.

Comment: you may want to remove id attribute from `item_level` elements because IDs are supposed to be unique. you already are using `class` attribute to them, so fetching those elements through `class` should do.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Forgot to remove that, thanks for pointing it out, but doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems and their solutions:

- IDs are supposed to be unique. You had same ID `#item_level` applied to multiple elements. But you already had applied a similar `class` applied to them as well, we will just use that and remove the extra ID attribute from the HTML.
- Your `keypress` event needed a way to tell which field had fired the event. We achieve that by using jQuery's **[`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** method.
- Your `click` event also needed a way to identify which of the two images were clicked. Again, `.index()` helps here. But we also use a method called **[`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to which we feed the `index` previously fetched. I hope I am making sense here.

Take a look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p412ksfc/)** and let me know if it helps.

***JavaScript:***

```
$('.image').click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    var e_type_var = $(this).parent().data('custom-data'),
        item_level_var = $(this).siblings('.footer').find('.item_level').val();
    forgeAjax(e_type_var, item_level_var, 'first_req', function (error) {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Close',
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }]
        });
        $('.ui-dialog button:eq(1)').focus();
        if (!error) {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                buttons: {
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                        'Button2': function () {
                        $('#message').html('');
                        startProgressBar(e_type_var, item_level_var);
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.ui-dialog button:eq(2)').focus();
        }
    });
});
$('.item_level').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('.image').eq($('.item_level').index(this)).click();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great stuff! The other answer works but I like this solution the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
$(".image").click(function () {
    //console.log("Let's Start! Image container was clicked");
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    var e_type_var = $(".container").data("custom-data"),
```

by

```
$(".image").click(function (e) {
    //console.log("Let's Start! Image container was clicked");
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    var e_type_var = $(e.target).closest('.container').data("custom-data"),
```

$(e.target) is the element that produce the event (remember pass the e in the event function)

closest search the near parent with this selector.

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

For the keypress you can use class name as aznbanana9 said, and plus this use the same strategy

```
$('.item_level').keypress(function (e) {
    // Enter was pressed while in the input box.
    if (e.which == 13) {
        // Send .image container click.
        $(e.target).closest('.container').find('.image').click();
```

This without change your code, probably here i call directly the function

I update the code http://jsfiddle.net/qjs7c86v/71/

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle had this:

```
$('#item_level').keypress(function (e) {
      // Enter was pressed while in the input box.
      if (e.which == 13) {
          // Send .image container click.
          $('.image').click();
      }
});
```

Which is selecting elements based on `id`. But your inputs have the same `id` fields, which are supposed to be unique:

```
<input type="text" name="item_level1" value="1" id="item_level" class="item_level" min="1" step="1" required>
```

AND

```
<input type="text" name="item_level2" value="1" id="item_level" class="item_level" min="1" step="1" required>
```

So, you can add another `$('#item_level').keypress(function ...` or just change your selector to find classes with the same name:

```
$('.item_level').keypress(function (e) {
      // Enter was pressed while in the input box.
      if (e.which == 13) {
          // Send .image container click.
          $('.image').click();
      }
});
```

---

More on jQuery selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp